# Laravel generate password and insert user in database by hand

Tags: laravel, authentication, password-hash

I have few users with no email and password, and I would like to update users by adding email from `freemail` column, and `setup password` from random string.

This is my sample code:

```
public function updateUserProfil()
{
    //find list user to be update(juste one to test)
    $users = User::where('isfree', '1')->first();
    //Random string generate
    $motdepasse = str_random(6);
    //find user
    $updateUser= User::find($users->id); 
    //setup fields
    $updateUser->email = $users->freemail;
    $updateUser->remember_token = str_random(10);
    $updateUser->motdepasse = $motdepasse;
    $updateUser->password = bcrypt($motdepasse);
    $updateUser->isfree = 0;
    $updateUser->save();
}
```

The problem is that when I try to connect  with `email($users->freemail)` and `password($motdepasse)`, which is not encrypted random string, I get error that:

> my credential is not valid

what did I miss ?

Comment: Did you check if `$updateUser->save()` returns `true`, so that you can be sure the data has been updated successfully? By the way, you should use `Hash::make($password)` instead of `bcrypt($password)` for consistency, in case the hashing algorithm changes in future (happened in v5.6, but it is configurable).

Comment: yes save is good, I get hash string and email but seems not corresponding to Auth encryption

Answer (score 0):

You can use update() to update rows. So your code must be

```
public function updateUserProfil()
{
    //find list user to be update(juste one to test)
    $users = User::where('isfree', '1')->first();
    //Random string generate
    $motdepasse = str_random(6);
    //find user
    $updateUser= User::find($users->id);
    //setup fields
    $updateUser->update([
        'email'=>$users->freemail,
        'remember_token'=>str_random(10),
        'motdepasse'=>$motdepasse,
        'password'=>bcrypt($motdepasse),
        'isfree'=>0,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Hi Samir, problem is not update. I get password hash string and email in user row but when I try to connect , credentials is still not valide.Is there Auth function  to encrypt password ?or bcrypt() method is used by auth ?

Comment: What do you mean by saying 'try to connect' ? Are you want to user login to account with password generated in `$motdepasse` ? Are you using Laravel's auth functions ? Or you override them?

Comment: yes I want to user login to account with password generated in $motdepasse. and I am using original Auth login form.

Comment: Are you changed $this->username() function? In default Laravel checks username column in login attempt. Looks like everything is right. Add your login.blade.php with [https://pastebin.com/](https://pastebin.com/) @fred

Comment: no I haven't change  original login function .please check my login.blade.php file. https://pastebin.com/RqAXD2m3

Comment: ok I updated  all users by recreate from copy table and New User function